# Emulate reading a tag on an Android phone

Tags: android, nfc

Is it possible to inject previously recorded NFC sequences into NFC stack in Android, so that the applications on the phone would think that tags are being read?

**Edit:**

Sorry for bad description

I don't have any code I'm just investigating the possibilities here.
In short what I want to achieve is this:
There is a FGM Sensor Called FreeStyle Libre, which in (v1) can only be read via NFC. I want to create a "dongle" that will read the sensor and forward the raw data to the phone via bluetooth. Some things like that exist but I want to use the original application for it (raw data is processed via specialized algorithm), so the idea for injecting somehow the data from a BLE receiver app into Android stack where the application is running, low level API might not be necessary, perhaps I've overstated the NFC stack. I've read somewhere that I could inject this on with a higher API (NDEF injection something like that).

Comment: Potentially. What code have you got? and we might be able to help https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Not in to the NFC stack, but possibly higher up depending on how you read the cards and what type of cards, for a better answer give details and code examples of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom build of Android, where you modify the OS to introduce <strike>security flaws</strike> APIs that would allow an app to spoof NFC tags, then yes.

Otherwise, no (unless there happens to be an existing unpatched security flaw somewhere).